# Why does the unsolvabililty of the Halting Problem imply the unsolvability of the Entscheidungsproblem?

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability, turing-machines

Let $\Phi$ be a recursively axiomatizable, consistent arithmetic theory. The unsolvability of the Entscheidungsproblem means that the set of theorems of $\Phi$  is not recursively decidable. That is, there is no algorithm that determines whether a given sentence $\varphi$ satisfies $\Phi\vdash\varphi$ or not. A proof of that fact can be found in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61156/342242).

However, I'm interested in the proof that reduces the Entscheidungsproblem to the halting problem (which is, as far as I know, the historical proof given by Turing). The line of reasoning is that, given a Turing machine $M$  we can assign a first-order $\Sigma_1$ sentence $\varphi_M$ that states the halting of $M$ on the empty input. More explicitly, $\varphi_M$ is the sentence $\exists n H(M,n)$ where $H(M,n)$  is a first-order arithmetic formula  that expresses the relation "$M$ halts (on the empty input) within $n$ steps".

Now, the proof claims that $M$ halts on the empty input if and only if $\Phi\vdash\varphi_M$. One direction is clear to me: if $M$ indeed halts, then there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\Phi\vdash H(M,n_0)$ and therefore $\Phi\vdash \varphi_M$. However, I fail to see how the second direction follows. If $\Phi\vdash\exists n H(M,n)$, it doesn't necessarily imply that there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ with $H(M,n_0)$; the promised $n_0$ might be non-standard.

Of course, this can be solved by restricting ourselves to theories $\Phi$ with $\mathbb{N}$ as a model. But I'd like to avoid that. Is there a way to overcome this problem and get a version of Turing's proof which applies to the more general case of the theory $\Phi$?

Comment: See Boolos, Burgess & Jeffrey, **Ch.11 The Undecidability of First-Order Logic**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, the proof claims that $M$ halts on the empty input if and only if $\Phi\vdash\varphi_M$.

This is indeed not true if all you know about $\Phi$ is that it is is recursively axiomatizable, consistent, and "can express enough arithmetic" (say, in the sense of proving all of primitive recursive arithmetic).

For a counterexample: Let $G_{\mathrm{PA}}$ be the Gödel sentence for first-order Peano Arithmetic. Let $M$ be a machine that searches for a proof of $G_{\mathrm{PA}}$ from PA. Finally let $\Phi = \mathrm{PA}+\neg G_{\mathrm{PA}}$.

Since $G_{\mathrm{PA}}$ is independent of PA, we know that $M$ does not in fact terminate, and that $\Phi$ is consistent.

However, $\Phi$ thinks $G_{\mathrm{PA}}$ is *false*, which is to say (recalling how Gödel's construction works) that there *is* a proof of $G_{\mathrm{PA}}$ from $PA$. Therefore $\Phi$ will believe that $M$ does terminate -- or in less informal terms, $\Phi \vdash \varphi_M$ holds.

The claim you cite works only if we can assume that $\Phi$ is a *true* theory of arithmetic (meaning that $\mathbb N$ is a model) -- or at least that it is $\omega$-consistent.

(And I doubt there is any way to make the entire argument work without *somehow* sneaking in an assumption that sufficiently strong true theories exist in the first place. Better have that assumption out in the open).

Comment: It appears quite circular proof. To prove the system consistent or $\omega$ consistent we use system that basically assumes it is consistent. A lot like the model theoretic proof of consistency of $PA$.